# Pinescript - coding a flip/flop array

Tags: pine-script

I am using bollinger band crossovers as entry/exit signals:

```
smaValue = sma(close, 20)
stdDev   = stdev(close, 20)
upperBand = smaValue + (stdDev * 2)
lowerBand = smaValue - (stdDev * 2)

buy = crossover(close, upperBand)
sell = crossunder(close, lowerBand)
```

I would like to create a signal array like a flip/flop mechanism:

https://www.amibroker.com/guide/afl/flip.html

So signalarray = 1 from the time a buy is given, stays a 1, and then when a sell is given, it turns to 0 - and stays 0 until a new buy is reached.

How would this be done in pine?

Comment: You will be expecting this ExRem: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74418876/14219797)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `var` keyword to declare a variable that maintains it's state. The example uses the `bool` type, but if you prefer the 1/0 flip, you can use the `int` type and 1 & 0 instead of true/false.

```
//@version=4
study("flip/flop", overlay = false)

smaValue = sma(close, 20)
stdDev   = stdev(close, 20)
upperBand = smaValue + (stdDev * 2)
lowerBand = smaValue - (stdDev * 2)

buy = crossover(close, upperBand)
sell = crossunder(close, lowerBand)

var bool isBuy = na
var bool isSell = na

if buy
    isBuy := true
    isSell := false
if sell
    isBuy := false
    isSell := true
    
plot(isBuy ? 1 : 0, color = color.green)
plot(isSell ? 1 : 0, color = color.red)
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks rumpypumpydumpy :) It also helped with my cannot call plot with series [bool] errors - I needed to convert to int

Answer (score 0):

Removes Excessive Signals:

Code Example, replace with your conditions:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='SuperTrend + MACD + EMA', overlay=true)

//EMA
fast_ema = ta.ema(close, 9)
slow_ema = ta.ema(close, 18)
plot(series=fast_ema, title='Fast EMA', color=#00FFFF, linewidth=1)
plot(series=slow_ema, title='Slow EMA', color=#FF00FF, linewidth=1)

//MACD
fastInput = 12
slowInput = 26
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, fastInput, slowInput, 9)

//Supertrend
atrPeriod = 10
factor = 3
[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)
linecolor = direction < 0 ? #00ff00 : #ff0000
plot(series=supertrend, title='Supertrend', color=linecolor, linewidth=1)

// Conditions
long_condition = barstate.isconfirmed and
                 fast_ema > slow_ema and
                 macdLine > signalLine and
                 close > supertrend

short_condition = barstate.isconfirmed and
                 fast_ema < slow_ema and
                 macdLine < signalLine and
                 close < supertrend

// Function to Remove Excessive Signals
exrem(condition_1, condition_2) =>
    var entry_signal = 0
    entry_signal := condition_1 ? 1 : condition_2 ? -1 : entry_signal[1]
    entry = entry_signal != entry_signal[1]
    buy = entry and entry_signal == 1
    sell = entry and entry_signal == -1
    [buy, sell]

// Signals
[long_signal, short_signal] = exrem(long_condition, short_condition)

// Plot
plotshape(long_signal, style=shape.triangleup, color=#00FF00, text='BUY', textcolor=#FFFFFF, editable=false, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small)
plotshape(short_signal, style=shape.triangledown, color=#FF0000, text='SELL', textcolor=#FFFFFF, editable=false, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small)
```

Result:

[image]