# IF AND statement plotarrow

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

For example:

```
if close > close[1] and (ta.wpr(3) > -20)
```

If this condition is `true` than the close candle will have triangle up sign.

```
if close > close[1] and WillR(3)<-70
```

If this condition is `true` than the close candle will have triangle down sign.

I want to have a code that `if` statement turns `true` or `false`, the drawing will say sell or buy.

What should be the code in pine script?

Answer (score 1):

I changed your `If` statement into a one-liner, so it will return `true` or `false`, instead of creating a local scope. For the triangle thingy you can use `plotshape()`. All in all it will look like this ...

```
bool conditionA = close > close[1] and ta.wpr(3) > -20 and barstate.isconfirmed
plotshape(conditionA, "A", shape.triangleup)

bool conditionB = close > close[1] and WillR(3)< -70 and barstate.isconfirmed
plotshape(conditionB, "B", shape.triangledown)
```

Not sure what `WillR(3)` will do, cause you left that part out. And I am not sure `close > close[1]` is what you want for `conditionB`, cause `close > close[1]` means actual price is higher than previous price. Maybe you should invert this to look like `close < close[1]`, meaning last price was higher than actual price.

Btw I added `and barstate.isconfirmed` to both lines which will prevent repainting.

Comment: i found this topic and modified it. the next mission is making it a strategy to find the profit ratio.  You can help me :-))) thanks                 Pine Script - Buy/Sell indicator for TradingView that meets multiple conditions                       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70475890/pine-script-buy-sell-indicator-for-tradingview-that-meets-multiple-conditions?rq=1